# Trigger an initialising webjob on VSO Release

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-webjobs

We have a webjob that performs certain initialization tasks post deployment.  We are deploying to an AppService in Azure and this is all working well including the deployment of the webjob.

I m currently able to login to the Azure portal and execute/trigger the webJob manually which is a work around but creates a manual step in the deployment.

Does anyone know how I can use CLI or similar to trigger the run from within the VSO release scripts.

Comment: Please refer to: [Ask], as you did not show a [MCVE]. You also didn't even bother to complete the 2-minute site tour before asking.

Comment: what type of webjob are you using ?

Comment: Do you success to trigger web job with my way?

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger WebJob through REST API ([Kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API)).

```
    param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[string]$websiteName,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[string]$webjobName
)

$website = Get-AzureWebsite $websiteName
$publishingUsername = $website.PublishingUsername
$publishingPassword = $website.PublishingPassword
$base64AuthInfo = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $publishingUsername, $publishingPassword)))

write-host Attempting to trigger backup job;
Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Uri https://$websiteName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/jobs/triggered/$webjobName/run -Method Post -ContentType application/json

#wait for webjob to complete - you may have a nicer way to know the webjob has completed
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
```

More information, you can refer to this article: [How to remotely trigger an Azure web job](https://the-angry-coder.com/2016/02/08/remotely-trigger-an-azure-webjob/)

Steps to run PowerShell during the build/release

1. Add Azure PowerShell step/task to build/release definition
2. Select Azure Classic
3. Select Subscription
4. Select PowerShell Script file path
5. Specify arguments

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VSTS Build & Release then you can use [Service Hooks](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/service-hooks/services/webhooks). There are quite a few VSTS events that can trigger a Web Hook call. The Url to run your web job can be had from the portal by clicking on your WebJob->Properties and you would use Basic Auth with the deployment credentials from the properties page.

[image]